# Android O: Extending HIDL files error

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to extend android.hardware.audio@2.0::IDevicesFactory to add a new Audio HAL.

So I copied whole 2.0 folder into 2.1 folder, and attempted to extend interface. This is my new IDevicesFactory.hal file:

```
package android.hardware.audio@2.1;

import android.hardware.audio@2.0::types;
import android.hardware.audio@2.0::IDevicesFactory;
import android.hardware.audio.common@2.0;
import IDevice;

interface IDevicesFactory EXTENDS android.hardware.audio@2.0::IDevicesFactory {
    typedef android.hardware.audio@2.0::Result Result;

    enum Device : int32_t {
        PRIMARY,
        A2DP,
        USB,
        R_SUBMIX,
        STUB,
        MY_HAL
    };
 };
```

[Removed code commentary for readability]

I only wish to add `MY_HAL` into that enum.

I don't know if I need to extend all interfaces, but I will do that. I will also modify all sources in my 2.1 folder to use @2.1 HIDL (namespaces and types etc).

I tried running `hardware/interfaces/update-makefiles.sh` and it throws following error:

```
gps@gps-HP-280-G3-MT:~/andsrc/android-8.0.0_r12$ hardware/interfaces/update-makefiles.sh
Updating makefiles for android.hardware in hardware/interfaces.
Updating android.hardware.audio@2.0
Updating android.hardware.audio@2.1
ERROR: syntax error at hardware/interfaces/audio/2.1/IDevicesFactory.hal:8.27-33
ERROR: syntax error at hardware/interfaces/audio/2.1/IDevicesFactory.hal:19.2
ERROR: Could not parse android.hardware.audio@2.1::IDevicesFactory. Aborting.
```

I do not understand why is there a Syntax error. Can someone guide me what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.

I misinterpreted the grammar for HIDL, and used upper case `EXTENDS` instead of lower case `extends`

Comment: I also found that it is probably impossible to extend HIDL in the way I wanted to.